# Translating a mixed-integer programming formulation to Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, linear-programming

### Problem Summary

To match passengers (the number of passengers) to capacitated vehicles such that the profit is increased. All the vehicles have the same capacity c. It is not important to track which passenger is matched to which vehicle.

### Problem Background

I'm trying to find a solution to the following passenger-matching problem:

The network is represented by graph G=(V,E). Graph G is a complete graph, The Edge e_ij is the edge between nodes i and j. V is the set of nodes/stations. p_{ij} is the profit of traveling through an edge (i,j). Let N be the number of vehicles, all the vehicles have the same capacity c.

At each (discreet) time step, the passengers arrive at their origin station i, and need to be transported to their destination station j. d_{ij} is the demand. f_{ij} <= d_{ij} is the passenger flow, i.e., the number of passengers that are traveling from i to j at time t and are successfully matched to a vehicle. The unmatched passers will leave the system. X_i is the total number of available vehicles at station i at time t.

#### Objective

The objective is to maximize profit.

[image: problem formulation]

I would like to solve the above formulation in Scipy and solve it using `milp()`. Eq. (2) ensures that the number of vehicles leaving node i is not more than the available vehicles at this node. Equations 3 and 4 bounds the flow to the maximum demand and capacity of the vehicles.

I have difficulty in translating the formulation to Scipy `milp` code. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some pointers.

### What I have done:

**The code for equation (1):**

```
f_obj = [p[i] for i in Edge]
x_obj = [0]*len(Edge)
obj = f_obj + v_obj
```

**Integrality:**

```
f_cont = [0 for i in Edge] # continous
x_int = [1]*len(Edge)  # integer
integrality = f_cont + x_int
```

**Equation (2):**

```
def constraints(self):
    b = []
    A = []
    const = [0]*len(Edge)  # for f_ij
    for i in region:  # for x_ij
        for e in Edge:
            if e[0] == i:
                const.append(1)
            else:
                const.append(0)
        A.append(const)
        b.append(self.accInit[i])
        const = [0]*len(Edge)  # for f_ij

    return A, b
```

**Equation (4):**

```
[(0, demand[e]) for e in Edge]
```

### Update

CPLEX code:

```
# Flow[e] == f_ij
# vehicleCount[e] == x_ij

maximize(sum(e in Edge) Flow[e]*prices[e]);
subject to
{

    forall(e in Edge)
            Flow[e] <= demand[e];  

        
    forall(i in region)    
        sum(e in Edge: e.i==i)vehicleCount[e]  <= init_car[i];  

    forall(e in Edge)
            Flow[e] <= capacity*vehicleCount[e]; 

}
```

Minimum sample data:

```
Edge = [(0, 1), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 0), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 10), (1, 13), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 11), (3, 13), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 11), (4, 13), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 10), (5, 12), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 5), (6, 7), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 13), (7, 0), (7, 2), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 9), (8, 12), (8, 13), (8, 14), (9, 0), (9, 2), (9, 4), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 11), (9, 12), (9, 14), (9, 15), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 9), (10, 14), (11, 3), (11, 6), (11, 7), (11, 9), (11, 13), (11, 15), (12, 4), (12, 9), (12, 10), (13, 6), (13, 7), (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 15), (14, 6), (14, 7), (14, 15), (15, 2), (15, 3), (15, 7), (15, 10), (15, 13), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (9, 9)]

# demand[Edge]={(src, dst): demand}
demand = {(0, 1): 1, (0, 5): 1, (0, 6): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 3): 1, (1, 5): 2, (1, 7): 1, (1, 10): 1, (1, 13): 1, (2, 0): 2, (2, 1): 1, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 1, (2, 5): 1, (2, 6): 5, (2, 7): 2, (2, 8): 2, (2, 9): 3, (2, 10): 2, (2, 11): 2, (2, 12): 1, (3, 1): 1, (3, 2): 1, (3, 5): 1, (3, 6): 1, (3, 9): 2, (3, 11): 1, (3, 13): 1, (4, 2): 1, (4, 3): 1, (4, 5): 5, (4, 7): 4, (4, 8): 1, (4, 11): 3, (4, 13): 1, (5, 0): 1, (5, 1): 2, (5, 2): 1, (5, 4): 3, (5, 6): 3, (5, 7): 2, (5, 8): 1, (5, 10): 1, (5, 12): 1, (6, 1): 2, (6, 2): 1, (6, 3): 1, (6, 5): 1, (6, 7): 5, (6, 9): 4, (6, 10): 1, (6, 13): 1, (7, 0): 1, (7, 2): 1, (7, 5): 1, (7, 6): 3, (7, 9): 4, (7, 10): 1, (7, 11): 1, (8, 4): 2, (8, 5): 2, (8, 6): 1, (8, 9): 2, (8, 12): 2, (8, 13): 2, (8, 14): 1, (9, 0): 2, (9, 2): 2, (9, 4): 3, (9, 5): 5, (9, 6): 1, (9, 7): 1, (9, 11): 1, (9, 12): 3, (9, 14): 1, (9, 15): 2, (10, 3): 1, (10, 4): 1, (10, 9): 1, (10, 14): 1, (11, 3): 1, (11, 6): 6, (11, 7): 4, (11, 9): 1, (11, 13): 1, (11, 15): 1, (12, 4): 1, (12, 9): 1, (12, 10): 1, (13, 6): 1, (13, 7): 1, (13, 8): 1, (13, 9): 1, (13, 15): 1, (14, 6): 1, (14, 7): 2, (14, 15): 1, (15, 2): 1, (15, 3): 1, (15, 7): 1, (15, 10): 1, (15, 13): 2, (1, 1): 2, (2, 2): 3, (3, 3): 4, (4, 4): 1, (5, 5): 1, (6, 6): 2, (7, 7): 4, (9, 9): 1}

# prices[Edge] = {(src, dst): price}
prices = {(0, 1): 7.1, (0, 5): 8.626999999999999, (0, 6): 11.568749999999998, (1, 0): 8.120000000000001, (1, 3): 8.425, (1, 5): 10.23125, (1, 7): 11.500000000000004, (1, 10): 13.633333333333331, (1, 13): 13.999999999999998, (2, 0): 7.558333333333335, (2, 1): 8.733333333333333, (2, 3): 6.610999999999999, (2, 4): 8.899999999999999, (2, 5): 9.883333333333331, (2, 6): 9.159523809523812, (2, 7): 9.978749999999998, (2, 8): 12.54, (2, 9): 11.6625, (2, 10): 13.3, (2, 11): 12.800000000000002, (2, 12): 15.6, (3, 1): 9.136000000000001, (3, 2): 6.163103448275866, (3, 5): 13.050000000000006, (3, 6): 10.143928571428571, (3, 9): 15.787499999999998, (3, 11): 11.0, (3, 13): 20.4, (4, 2): 9.042499999999999, (4, 3): 7.249999999999998, (4, 5): 7.123913043478264, (4, 7): 11.058518518518518, (4, 8): 6.87142857142857, (4, 11): 14.36714285714286, (4, 13): 8.120000000000001, (5, 0): 6.35, (5, 1): 8.975000000000001, (5, 2): 8.329999999999998, (5, 4): 6.177419354838713, (5, 6): 7.2321428571428585, (5, 7): 9.6675, (5, 8): 7.130000000000001, (5, 10): 9.049999999999999, (5, 12): 13.999999999999998, (6, 1): 8.66, (6, 2): 7.873571428571429, (6, 3): 7.374999999999999, (6, 5): 6.726818181818181, (6, 7): 6.7074509803921485, (6, 9): 9.031200000000002, (6, 10): 8.143846153846155, (6, 13): 11.754999999999999, (7, 0): 14.3, (7, 2): 7.551818181818183, (7, 5): 9.354545454545454, (7, 6): 9.2275, (7, 9): 10.295625, (7, 10): 9.450000000000001, (7, 11): 9.237000000000002, (8, 4): 7.270952380952383, (8, 5): 8.730909090909092, (8, 6): 10.31923076923077, (8, 9): 9.78, (8, 12): 8.796153846153846, (8, 13): 9.3, (8, 14): 14.87333333333333, (9, 0): 9.892857142857142, (9, 2): 12.05909090909091, (9, 4): 7.990909090909093, (9, 5): 9.074333333333334, (9, 6): 9.919354838709681, (9, 7): 11.73782608695652, (9, 11): 8.61, (9, 12): 8.033333333333335, (9, 14): 9.086666666666668, (9, 15): 8.366666666666665, (10, 3): 12.275000000000002, (10, 4): 10.214285714285715, (10, 9): 7.441428571428574, (10, 14): 6.711111111111111, (11, 3): 9.25, (11, 6): 8.576451612903226, (11, 7): 8.644333333333334, (11, 9): 9.09857142857143, (11, 13): 9.299999999999999, (11, 15): 5.973571428571427, (12, 4): 9.899999999999999, (12, 9): 10.266666666666667, (12, 10): 11.299999999999997, (13, 6): 12.000000000000002, (13, 7): 12.4, (13, 8): 11.416666666666664, (13, 9): 8.0375, (13, 15): 6.5, (14, 6): 12.323999999999998, (14, 7): 12.277777777777775, (14, 15): 5.373333333333334, (15, 2): 15.249999999999998, (15, 3): 17.999999999999996, (15, 7): 10.375, (15, 10): 9.9625, (15, 13): 9.199999999999998, (1, 1): 15.12111111111111, (2, 2): 5.354666666666667, (3, 3): 6.814285714285714, (4, 4): 5.949999999999999, (5, 5): 6.486842105263157, (6, 6): 8.116086956521741, (7, 7): 8.7425, (9, 9): 6.1} 


# init_car[region] = {region: initial_no_cars}
init_car = {0: 3.0, 1: 34.0, 2: 82.0, 3: 57.0, 4: 16.0, 5: 28.0, 6: 39.0, 7: 43.0, 8: 11.0, 9: 25.0, 10: 13.0, 11: 25.0, 12: 94.0, 13: 32.0, 14: 9.0, 15: 15.0}
```

Transformed the above-data to be used for Reinderien code

```
Price= [7.1, 8.626999999999999, 11.568749999999998, 8.120000000000001, 8.425, 10.23125, 11.500000000000004, 13.633333333333331, 13.999999999999998, 7.558333333333335, 8.733333333333333, 6.610999999999999, 8.899999999999999, 9.883333333333331, 9.159523809523812, 9.978749999999998, 12.54, 11.6625, 13.3, 12.800000000000002, 15.6, 9.136000000000001, 6.163103448275866, 13.050000000000006, 10.143928571428571, 15.787499999999998, 11.0, 20.4, 9.042499999999999, 7.249999999999998, 7.123913043478264, 11.058518518518518, 6.87142857142857, 14.36714285714286, 8.120000000000001, 6.35, 8.975000000000001, 8.329999999999998, 6.177419354838713, 7.2321428571428585, 9.6675, 7.130000000000001, 9.049999999999999, 13.999999999999998, 8.66, 7.873571428571429, 7.374999999999999, 6.726818181818181, 6.7074509803921485, 9.031200000000002, 8.143846153846155, 11.754999999999999, 14.3, 7.551818181818183, 9.354545454545454, 9.2275, 10.295625, 9.450000000000001, 9.237000000000002, 7.270952380952383, 8.730909090909092, 10.31923076923077, 9.78, 8.796153846153846, 9.3, 14.87333333333333, 9.892857142857142, 12.05909090909091, 7.990909090909093, 9.074333333333334, 9.919354838709681, 11.73782608695652, 8.61, 8.033333333333335, 9.086666666666668, 8.366666666666665, 12.275000000000002, 10.214285714285715, 7.441428571428574, 6.711111111111111, 9.25, 8.576451612903226, 8.644333333333334, 9.09857142857143, 9.299999999999999, 5.973571428571427, 9.899999999999999, 10.266666666666667, 11.299999999999997, 12.000000000000002, 12.4, 11.416666666666664, 8.0375, 6.5, 12.323999999999998, 12.277777777777775, 5.373333333333334, 15.249999999999998, 17.999999999999996, 10.375, 9.9625, 9.199999999999998, 15.12111111111111, 5.354666666666667, 6.814285714285714, 5.949999999999999, 6.486842105263157, 8.116086956521741, 8.7425, 6.1]
Demand= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1]
Availability= [3.0, 34.0, 82.0, 57.0, 16.0, 28.0, 39.0, 43.0, 11.0, 25.0, 13.0, 25.0, 94.0, 32.0, 9.0, 15.0]
```

Comment: Maybe someone who has used https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html a lot will see the question, and give a quick answer.  But that could take days.  For ordinary scipy users, you need to tell us more - are you getting errors?  having difficulty understanding the function docs?  Do you understand the documented examples?

Comment: This is not reproducible - you have not shown what `Edge` is. Also, (1) makes no sense - it's an orphaned expression that's missing a relation

Comment: My apologies!  @hpaulj my main problem was how to convert this into matrix form. Since Scipy requires the formulation to be in matrix form.

Comment: You still haven't shown a real capacity variable to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to do some wild guessing, given how much you've left open to interpretation. Let's assume that

- this is a maximisation problem, since the minimisation problem is trivial
- Expression (1) is actually the maximisation objective function, though you failed to write it as such
- `p` and `d` are floating-point vectors
- `X` is an integer vector
- `c` is a floating-point scalar
- the graph edges, since you haven't described them at all, do not matter for problem setup

The variable names are not well-chosen and hide what they actually contain. I demonstrate potential replacements.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random._generator import Generator
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse
from numpy.random import default_rng


# Edges between a source and destination location
edges = (( 0,  1), ( 0,  5), ( 0,  6), ( 1,  0), ( 1,  3), ( 1,  5), ( 1,  7), ( 1, 10), ( 1, 13),
         ( 2,  0), ( 2,  1), ( 2,  3), ( 2,  4), ( 2,  5), ( 2,  6), ( 2,  7), ( 2,  8), ( 2,  9),
         ( 2, 10), ( 2, 11), ( 2, 12), ( 3,  1), ( 3,  2), ( 3,  5), ( 3,  6), ( 3,  9), ( 3, 11),
         ( 3, 13), ( 4,  2), ( 4,  3), ( 4,  5), ( 4,  7), ( 4,  8), ( 4, 11), ( 4, 13), ( 5,  0),
         ( 5,  1), ( 5,  2), ( 5,  4), ( 5,  6), ( 5,  7), ( 5,  8), ( 5, 10), ( 5, 12), ( 6,  1),
         ( 6,  2), ( 6,  3), ( 6,  5), ( 6,  7), ( 6,  9), ( 6, 10), ( 6, 13), ( 7,  0), ( 7,  2),
         ( 7,  5), ( 7,  6), ( 7,  9), ( 7, 10), ( 7, 11), ( 8,  4), ( 8,  5), ( 8,  6), ( 8,  9),
         ( 8, 12), ( 8, 13), ( 8, 14), ( 9,  0), ( 9,  2), ( 9,  4), ( 9,  5), ( 9,  6), ( 9,  7),
         ( 9, 11), ( 9, 12), ( 9, 14), ( 9, 15), (10,  3), (10,  4), (10,  9), (10, 14), (11,  3),
         (11,  6), (11,  7), (11,  9), (11, 13), (11, 15), (12,  4), (12,  9), (12, 10), (13,  6),
         (13,  7), (13,  8), (13,  9), (13, 15), (14,  6), (14,  7), (14, 15), (15,  2), (15,  3),
         (15,  7), (15, 10), (15, 13), ( 1,  1), ( 2,  2), ( 3,  3), ( 4,  4), ( 5,  5), ( 6,  6),
         ( 7,  7), ( 9,  9))

# demand[Edge]={(src, dst): demand} aka. d
demand = {( 0,  1): 1, ( 0,  5): 1, ( 0,  6): 1, ( 1,  0): 1, ( 1,  3): 1, ( 1,  5): 2, ( 1,  7): 1,
          ( 1, 10): 1, ( 1, 13): 1, ( 2,  0): 2, ( 2,  1): 1, ( 2,  3): 3, ( 2,  4): 1, ( 2,  5): 1,
          ( 2,  6): 5, ( 2,  7): 2, ( 2,  8): 2, ( 2,  9): 3, ( 2, 10): 2, ( 2, 11): 2, ( 2, 12): 1,
          ( 3,  1): 1, ( 3,  2): 1, ( 3,  5): 1, ( 3,  6): 1, ( 3,  9): 2, ( 3, 11): 1, ( 3, 13): 1,
          ( 4,  2): 1, ( 4,  3): 1, ( 4,  5): 5, ( 4,  7): 4, ( 4,  8): 1, ( 4, 11): 3, ( 4, 13): 1,
          ( 5,  0): 1, ( 5,  1): 2, ( 5,  2): 1, ( 5,  4): 3, ( 5,  6): 3, ( 5,  7): 2, ( 5,  8): 1,
          ( 5, 10): 1, ( 5, 12): 1, ( 6,  1): 2, ( 6,  2): 1, ( 6,  3): 1, ( 6,  5): 1, ( 6,  7): 5,
          ( 6,  9): 4, ( 6, 10): 1, ( 6, 13): 1, ( 7,  0): 1, ( 7,  2): 1, ( 7,  5): 1, ( 7,  6): 3,
          ( 7,  9): 4, ( 7, 10): 1, ( 7, 11): 1, ( 8,  4): 2, ( 8,  5): 2, ( 8,  6): 1, ( 8,  9): 2,
          ( 8, 12): 2, ( 8, 13): 2, ( 8, 14): 1, ( 9,  0): 2, ( 9,  2): 2, ( 9,  4): 3, ( 9,  5): 5,
          ( 9,  6): 1, ( 9,  7): 1, ( 9, 11): 1, ( 9, 12): 3, ( 9, 14): 1, ( 9, 15): 2, (10,  3): 1,
          (10,  4): 1, (10,  9): 1, (10, 14): 1, (11,  3): 1, (11,  6): 6, (11,  7): 4, (11,  9): 1,
          (11, 13): 1, (11, 15): 1, (12,  4): 1, (12,  9): 1, (12, 10): 1, (13,  6): 1, (13,  7): 1,
          (13,  8): 1, (13,  9): 1, (13, 15): 1, (14,  6): 1, (14,  7): 2, (14, 15): 1, (15,  2): 1,
          (15,  3): 1, (15,  7): 1, (15, 10): 1, (15, 13): 2, ( 1,  1): 2, ( 2,  2): 3, ( 3,  3): 4,
          ( 4,  4): 1, ( 5,  5): 1, ( 6,  6): 2, ( 7,  7): 4, ( 9,  9): 1}

# prices[Edge] = {(src, dst): price}, aka. p aka. profit
prices = {(0, 1): 7.1, (0, 5): 8.626999999999999, (0, 6): 11.568749999999998,
          (1, 0): 8.120000000000001, (1, 3): 8.425, (1, 5): 10.23125, (1, 7): 11.500000000000004,
          (1, 10): 13.633333333333331, (1, 13): 13.999999999999998, (2, 0): 7.558333333333335,
          (2, 1): 8.733333333333333, (2, 3): 6.610999999999999, (2, 4): 8.899999999999999,
          (2, 5): 9.883333333333331, (2, 6): 9.159523809523812, (2, 7): 9.978749999999998,
          (2, 8): 12.54, (2, 9): 11.6625, (2, 10): 13.3, (2, 11): 12.800000000000002,
          (2, 12): 15.6, (3, 1): 9.136000000000001, (3, 2): 6.163103448275866,
          (3, 5): 13.050000000000006, (3, 6): 10.143928571428571, (3, 9): 15.787499999999998,
          (3, 11): 11.0, (3, 13): 20.4, (4, 2): 9.042499999999999, (4, 3): 7.249999999999998,
          (4, 5): 7.123913043478264, (4, 7): 11.058518518518518, (4, 8): 6.87142857142857,
          (4, 11): 14.36714285714286, (4, 13): 8.120000000000001, (5, 0): 6.35,
          (5, 1): 8.975000000000001, (5, 2): 8.329999999999998, (5, 4): 6.177419354838713,
          (5, 6): 7.2321428571428585, (5, 7): 9.6675, (5, 8): 7.130000000000001,
          (5, 10): 9.049999999999999, (5, 12): 13.999999999999998, (6, 1): 8.66,
          (6, 2): 7.873571428571429, (6, 3): 7.374999999999999, (6, 5): 6.726818181818181,
          (6, 7): 6.7074509803921485, (6, 9): 9.031200000000002, (6, 10): 8.143846153846155,
          (6, 13): 11.754999999999999, (7, 0): 14.3, (7, 2): 7.551818181818183,
          (7, 5): 9.354545454545454, (7, 6): 9.2275, (7, 9): 10.295625, (7, 10): 9.450000000000001,
          (7, 11): 9.237000000000002, (8, 4): 7.270952380952383, (8, 5): 8.730909090909092,
          (8, 6): 10.31923076923077, (8, 9): 9.78, (8, 12): 8.796153846153846, (8, 13): 9.3,
          (8, 14): 14.87333333333333, (9, 0): 9.892857142857142, (9, 2): 12.05909090909091,
          (9, 4): 7.990909090909093, (9, 5): 9.074333333333334, (9, 6): 9.919354838709681,
          (9, 7): 11.73782608695652, (9, 11): 8.61, (9, 12): 8.033333333333335,
          (9, 14): 9.086666666666668, (9, 15): 8.366666666666665, (10, 3): 12.275000000000002,
          (10, 4): 10.214285714285715, (10, 9): 7.441428571428574, (10, 14): 6.711111111111111,
          (11, 3): 9.25, (11, 6): 8.576451612903226, (11, 7): 8.644333333333334,
          (11, 9): 9.09857142857143, (11, 13): 9.299999999999999, (11, 15): 5.973571428571427,
          (12, 4): 9.899999999999999, (12, 9): 10.266666666666667, (12, 10): 11.299999999999997,
          (13, 6): 12.000000000000002, (13, 7): 12.4, (13, 8): 11.416666666666664, (13, 9): 8.0375,
          (13, 15): 6.5, (14, 6): 12.323999999999998, (14, 7): 12.277777777777775,
          (14, 15): 5.373333333333334, (15, 2): 15.249999999999998, (15, 3): 17.999999999999996,
          (15, 7): 10.375, (15, 10): 9.9625, (15, 13): 9.199999999999998, (1, 1): 15.12111111111111,
          (2, 2): 5.354666666666667, (3, 3): 6.814285714285714, (4, 4): 5.949999999999999,
          (5, 5): 6.486842105263157, (6, 6): 8.116086956521741, (7, 7): 8.7425, (9, 9): 6.1}

# it's a mystery
rand: Generator = default_rng(seed=0)
capacity = rand.integers(low=1, high=100)

# init_car[region] = {region: initial_no_cars} aka. X aka. accInit
init_car = {0: 3.0, 1: 34.0, 2: 82.0, 3: 57.0, 4: 16.0, 5: 28.0, 6: 39.0, 7: 43.0,
            8: 11.0, 9: 25.0, 10: 13.0, 11: 25.0, 12: 94.0, 13: 32.0, 14: 9.0, 15: 15.0}

N = len(prices)  # number of non-zero edges

c = np.zeros(2*N)  # f (passenger flow) and x (number of vehicles???)
# (1) f maximized with coefficients of 'p'
c[:N] = [-prices[edge] for edge in edges]
# x not optimized

CONTINUOUS = 0
INTEGER = 1
integrality = np.empty_like(c, dtype=int)
integrality[:N] = CONTINUOUS  # f
integrality[N:] = INTEGER     # x

upper = np.empty_like(c)
# (4) upper bound of f
upper[:N] = [demand[edge] for edge in edges]
# (2) upper bound of x
upper[N:] = [init_car[source] for source, dest in edges]

eye_N = scipy.sparse.eye(N)
# (3) 0 <= -f + cx
A = scipy.sparse.hstack((-eye_N, capacity*eye_N))

result = milp(
    c=c, integrality=integrality,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=np.zeros_like(c), ub=upper),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(lb=np.zeros(N), A=A),
)
print(result.message)
flow = result.x[:N]
vehicles = result.x[N:].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @reinderien! My apologies, I just realized I didn't specify what type of optimization it is. Yes, you are right it is a maximization problem.  however, both `c` and `d` are integer values. Unfortunately, because I gave my system for repair, I cannot test the code now. But I believe your code is what I needed... Thank you!

Comment: Dear Reinderien, it seems that there is a problem with constraint (2) because the size of `availability` and other variables are not the same. I tried to run it, but it gives me the following error: `could not broadcast input array from shape (16,) into shape (110,)`.   I tried to use my `constraints()` however I am not sure how to combine equations (2) and (3) for the constraints. Can you suggest how to solve this issue, please? based on your code I updated my question with sample data.

Comment: Makes no sense at all. If you have disparate array lengths, you need to spell out exactly what your network scheme looks like and why the lengths are different. As it stands, it's entirely impossible to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Nope. You've listed 110 prices and 16 vehicle counts (source nodes). For 16 source nodes in a complete graph I would expect 120 prices.

Comment: I see.  When there is no demand for i to j, there won't be any edge between these two nodes, so it isn't considered and no price will be assigned for it as well. So, for this particular example, there was no demand between some of the nodes. If it is any help, I added my CPLEX implementation to the question post.